# Преобразовать массив строк в словарь

Tags: python, массивы, словари

Добрый день! подскажите, пожалуйста, как вот такой массив:

```
 [['  RANGEBEGINNINGDATE=2012-07-16'], ['  GRINGPOINTLATITUDE=49.7622907843073, 60.0921799349341, 59.9299194433383, 49.6767523917138'], ['  GRINGPOINTLONGITUDE=61.938978123863, 80.0739959012183, 100.833098118661, 78.0161056882103']]
```

Привести к виду:

```
   {'RANGEBEGINNINGDATE' : '2012-07-16', 'GRINGPOINTLATITUDE': '49.7622907843073, 60.0921799349341, 59.9299194433383, 49.6767523917138', 'GRINGPOINTLONGITUDE': 61.938978123863, 80.0739959012183, 100.833098118661, 78.0161056882103'}
```

Т.е. разбить каждый элемент по знаку равно и потом разделить на ключ и значение.

Заранее  спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = [...] # ваш массив
print dict([x[0].strip().split('=') for x in a])
```